# Linked Server throws metadata error

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql

I have a function in SQL Server 2019 that copies data from a local table to an Oracle 11.2.0.4 table via Linked Server, using Oracle 19.3 client. Recently, a new column was added to the Oracle table, so I've updated the insert function to include this new column.

Now, whenever I modify the function, it will execute successfully one time and one time only. If I purge the query cache, it also executes once and then starts throwing the error from then on. ALL execution attempts after the first time throw this error:

> Msg 7353, Level 16, State 1, Procedure COD.Interface_Upload, Line
> 29 [Batch Start Line 20] The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for
> linked server "ORADEV-LINK" supplied inconsistent metadata. An extra
> column was supplied during execution that was not found at compile
> time.

The only change to this procedure from the previous, working, version is adding the DATE_SUBMITTED field and the "select min([Sample_date])  ..." part to supply that column.

Everything I can find says that if you're getting metadata errors, go to the OPENQUERY syntax, which is what I'm using.

The function is:

```
ALTER Procedure [COD].[Interface_Upload]
  As
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
    INSERT OPENQUERY([ORADEV-LINK], 'SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, FROM_DATE, TO_DATE, 
            COD_TO_BOD_FACTOR, CONSUMPTION, SAMPLE_DATE, COD_CONTENT, SS_CONTENT,
            DATE_SUBMITTED from cbd.WS_CBD_PACS')
        Select [Account_Number]
            ,[From_Date]        ,[To_Date]
            ,[Factor]           ,[Consumption]
            ,[Sample_date]      ,[COD]
            ,[SS]
            , ( select min([Sample_date]) 
                from dbo.ORA_Interface 
                where Account_Number = p.Account_Number )
        from dbo.ORA_Interface p ;

    Return @@rowcount;
GO
```

The Oracle destination table definition is:

```
                         Null?    Type
 ----------------------- -------- -------
 ACCOUNT_NUMBER          NOT NULL NUMBER(13)
 FROM_DATE               NOT NULL DATE
 TO_DATE                 NOT NULL DATE
 COD_TO_BOD_FACTOR       NOT NULL NUMBER(6,2)
 CONSUMPTION             NOT NULL NUMBER(15)
 SAMPLE_DATE             NOT NULL DATE
 COD_CONTENT             NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 SS_CONTENT              NOT NULL NUMBER(10)
 DATE_SUBMITTED                   DATE
```

The SQL Server source table definition is:

```
[Account_Number] [varchar](30) NULL,
[From_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[To_Date] [datetime] NULL,
[Factor] [numeric](15, 2) NULL,
[Consumption] [numeric](15, 2) NULL,
[Sample_date] [datetime] NULL,
[COD] [numeric](15, 2) NULL,
[SS] [numeric](15, 2) NULL
```

Comment: What happens if you pass you data through a temp table first?  E.g. Insert Into a temp table then use that temp table to do the cross server insert.  I suggest explicitly declaring your temp table if an implicit one doesn't work.

Comment: @Graham are you suggesting on the temp table on the Oracle side or the SQL side?

Comment: I tried switching back to a standard insert into .. select query and that failed. I've tried rebooting the SQL server; that failed too. I've even tried dropping the Oracle table and recreating it.

Comment: I was suggesting a temp table on the SQL Server side as an intermediary.

Comment: I changed to copy data to a #temp table, then copy from there to the Oracle table. Again, it runs fine the 1st time after issuing the Alter Proc statement, then fails on subsequent executions with the same error message.

Comment: For giggles, try adding an OPTION (RECOMPILE) on the INSERT.

Comment: @Graham, wow. I didn't even think to try that (duh moment). It worked, as far as I can tell.

Comment: I'll add that as an answer so in the future someone with the same issue doesn't need to wade through all the missteps to find out if things got sorted.

Comment: It appears this dates back to at least SQL Server 2005. Glad to know MS is fixing their bugs: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60475733-698d-45fe-947f-0e37f02f60fa/linked-server-schema-caching-results-in-query-errors?forum=sqldatabaseengine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem is an Oracle Bug. [Patch 31892754: 19C OLEDB PROVIDER EXECUTION FAILS WITH INCONSISTENT METADATA IN A LINKED SERVER](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchDetail?_afrLoop=376281425858500&patchId=31892754&_adf.ctrl-state=6kwjubzg1_249) addresses this problem.

It requires Oracle 19.3 and [CU 31247621](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchResultsNDetails?_adf.ctrl-state=6kwjubzg1_4&releaseId=600000000101150&requestId=23674370&patchId=31247621) (but no more recent CUs than that).

Oracle says this patch will be included in Oracle 19.11, so I'm assuming that's a CU due in 2021.

Edited to add:
The patch needs to be installed on the SQL Server side, applied to the Oracle Client on that SQL Server host.

Comment: Hi @CaM, we have the same problem, could you provide more details? Where did you install that fix: on the Oracle side (did an upgrade?) or on the SQL server where the 19.3 client has been installed? Thanks!

Comment: The fix was applied to the Oracle Client on the SQL Server side. In theory, a newer client version should already include the fix, but I've not confirmed that.

Answer (score 2):

Use `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` on the `INSERT`

Comment: Thank you! This one drove me nuts. May I ask why this works?

Comment: For an unknown reason reusing the a query plan is causing a failure. Instead of addressing the root cause (because I have no idea the root cause), I provided a workaround; the recompile avoids reusing a plan.

Comment: I wonder if this isn't some kind of bug on MS's part?

Comment: Turns out it's a bug on Oracle's part.